# Attempting to get *all classes* from elementHandle in Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Currently I am using

```
const element = await page.$('div.layout-board-section')
```

to get the elementHandle of the `div`. However, I then need to get the list of classes from that elementHandle. I've tried a couple different solutions though they all seem to only return the first class using `element.className` in an evaluate function.

Is there any way to get all of the classes of an element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a node's `.classList` property.

```
const classes = await page.$eval(
  'div.layout-board-section', 
  el => [...el.classList]
);
```

or if you already have an elementHandle:

```
const classes = await someElement.evaluate(el => [...el.classList]);
```

Complete example:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

let browser;
(async () => {
  const html = `<div class="foo bar baz quux">blahhh</div>`;
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setContent(html);

  const classes = await page.$eval("div", el => [...el.classList]);
  console.log(classes); // => [ 'foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'quux' ]

  // or with an elementHandle:
  const divEl = await page.$("div");
  console.log(await divEl.evaluate(el => [...el.classList]));
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

Comment: hey btw, just curious, do you know why, when you remove the copying stuff from `divEl.evaluate(el => [...el.classList])`, you get the classList array except that it's now an object with array indices as keys? Is there any documentation about this that you can refer me to?

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList. It returns a live [`DOMTokenList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList) class that has methods and is iterable, hence the indicies.